# Gradle Jacoco does not track the coverage of Spock test when using Powermock

Tags: java, gradle, powermock, jacoco

I am using Gradle `Jacoco` plugin to record the test coverage of our software. The software contains some legacy code that makes heavy use of static methods. In order to mock them we came up with Powermock and integrated it into our Spock tests.

Everything works fine some far. The *only* thing is that `Jacoco` does not track the test coverage of tests that are using Powermock. The coverage of tests of plain Spock tests (tests that do not use Powermock) are reported as expected.

Does anyone have a clue how to make `Jacoco` record the coverage of my Powermock tests?

Please find the Spock test below.

```
@PrepareForTest([CodeCacheManager])
class SampleSpec extends Specification {

 @Rule
 PowerMockRule powerMockRule = new PowerMockRule();

 @Unroll
 void "Convert CodeIdentifier #insertvalue toString #returnvalue"() {

    given:
    def converter = new CodeIdentifierCodeInternalNameCustomConverter()

    and:
    mockStatic(CodeCacheManager.class)
    Mockito.when(CodeCacheManager.getInternalNameForCode(insertvalue)).thenReturn(returnvalue)

    when:
    String value = converter.convertTo(insertvalue, null)

    then:
    value == returnvalue

    where:
    insertvalue                      | returnvalue
    PartnerCodes.Geschlecht.mannlich | "männlich"
    null                             | "NO INTERNAL NAME"
 }
}
```

and the implementation of the tested method looks

```
public String convertTo (CodeIdentifier source, String destination)
{
  if (source != null)
  {
     return CodeCacheManager.getInternalNameForCode (source);
  }
  return "NO INTERNAL NAME";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround? I am having the same issue

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerMock and Jacoco are incompatible and do not work when using them together.

Comment: what tool did you change to make the unit test covered?

Comment: I completely dropped PowerMock and started to redesign our software. Since we're using Java 8 you can replace e.g. static utility methods by using default method implementation in an interface. Therefore its just Spock and Jacoco.

Answer (score 3):

Jacoco Offline Instrumentation is the solution for this.

**see my gradle build file**

```
Build and run tests:
Linux:
\$ ./gradlew
Windows:
\$ gradlew
------------------------------------------
"""

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

// Project group and version
group 'com.abcd.jacocoTest'
version '1.0.0'

// JDK version source compatibility
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

// JDK version target compatibility
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    jacocoAnt
    jacocoRuntime
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "4.5.1"
}

defaultTasks 'clean', 'test'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    jacocoAnt group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.ant', version: '0.8.1'
    jacocoAgent group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.8.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.8.9'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.7.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '1.7.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-easymock', version: '1.7.4'

}

test {
    testLogging {
        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                println "Unit Tests: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
            }
        }
    }

    jacoco {
        append = "false"
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/jacoco-sonar/jacoco-coverage.exec")
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.0"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", 'JacocoTest'
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "${buildDir}/classes"
        property "sonar.java.libraries", "**/*.jar"
        property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco-sonar/jacoco-coverage.exec"
    }
}

task instrument(dependsOn: ['classes']) {
    ext.outputDir = buildDir.path + '/reports/classes-instrumented'
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'instrument',
                classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask',
                classpath: configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath)
        ant.instrument(destdir: outputDir) {
            fileset(dir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
        }
    }
}
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(instrument)) {
        tasks.withType(Test) {
            doFirst {
                classpath = files(instrument.outputDir) + classpath + configurations.jacocoRuntime
            }
        }
    }
}
task report(dependsOn: ['instrument', 'test']) {
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'report',
                classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask',
                classpath: configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath)
        ant.report() {
            executiondata {
                ant.file(file: buildDir.path + '/reports/jacoco/jacoco-sonar/jacoco-coverage.exec')
            }
            structure(name: 'Example') {
                classfiles {
                    fileset(dir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
                }
                sourcefiles {
                    fileset(dir: 'src/main/java')
                }
            }
            html(destdir: buildDir.path + '/reports/jacoco')
        }
    }
}
```

Here **report task** will create the offline instrumentation files of the project.

Finally, execute **sonarqube task**. Then you can see the coverage of the powermocked classes also has included.

```
Execution command ./gradlew report sonarqube
```

Then go and see in your sonarqube host (localhost:9000).