# Coverage not working for PowerMock, Jacoco and Sonarqube using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I've been thumping my head against this for a while now so I thought I'd open it up for someone to point out where I'm going wrong.

I'm using gradle 4.10, java 9.04, jacoco 0.8.4 and sonarqube 7.9. I've been trying to get my coverage to include the tests run using Powermock and I'm hitting a bit of a wall with the offline-resources. I've tried a variety of sources including:

- [Gradle Jacoco does not track the coverage of Spock test when using Powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325715/gradle-jacoco-does-not-track-the-coverage-of-spock-test-when-using-powermock/50432023)
- https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo
- [SonarQube: Coverage incomplete on multimodule gradle project with JaCoCo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737758/sonarqube-coverage-incomplete-on-multimodule-gradle-project-with-jacoco)
- [Gradle skipping jacoco coverage plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553349/gradle-skipping-jacoco-coverage-plugin)
- [SonarQube + Jacoco Coverage Discrepancies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601376/sonarqube-jacoco-coverage-discrepancies)

The changes I've made to the examples are largely around the deprecation of sourceSets.main.output.classesDir. I'm not committed to any of the plug versions I'm using, but I need to stick with Java 9 and Maven 4 for now. I'm happy to swap out jacoco or mockito if there is a better way of getting the same functionality.

I've tried to boil this down to as simple a problem as possible.

**Simple Application**

```
public class App {
    public void mockTest() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("Hello.txt"))) {
            //do stuff
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public String simpleMethod(){
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

**Simple Application Test**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.*", "com.sun.*"})
@PrepareForTest({App.class})
public class AppTest {

    @Test(expected = ClassNotFoundException.class)
    public void testAppHasAGreeting() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withParameterTypes(File.class).withArguments(any(File.class)).thenThrow(IOException.class);
        App app = new App();
        app.mockTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleMethod() {
        SimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass();
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello world", simpleClass.simpleMethod());
    }
}
```

**Gradle build**

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8" apply false
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
mainClassName = 'App'

configurations {
    jacocoAnt
    jacocoRuntime
}

dependencies {
    jacocoAnt group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.ant', version: '0.8.5'
    jacocoRuntime group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.8.5'
    <snip>
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://192.168.159.132:8051/"
        property "sonar.login", "11b80d093e28669fe5c31e17553b08258a91016f"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "${buildDir}/classes"
        property "sonar.java.libraries", "**/*.jar"
        property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "${buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "${buildDir}/test-results/test"
    }
}

task instrument(dependsOn: ['classes']) {
    ext.outputDir = buildDir.path + '/reports/classes-instrumented'
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'instrument',
                classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask',
                classpath: configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath)
        ant.instrument(destdir: outputDir) {
            for(File f :  sourceSets.main.output.getClassesDirs()){
                fileset(dir: f)
            }
        }
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(instrument)) {
        tasks.withType(Test) {
            doFirst {
                systemProperty 'jacoco-agent.destfile', buildDir.path + '/jacoco/tests.exec'
                classpath = files(instrument.outputDir) + classpath + configurations.jacocoRuntime
            }
        }
    }
}

task report(dependsOn: ['instrument', 'test']) {

    println "Source Classes" + sourceSets.main.output.getClassesDirs()

    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'report',
                classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask',
                classpath: configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath)
        ant.report() {
            executiondata {
                ant.file(file: buildDir.path + '/jacoco/test.exec')
            }
            structure(name: 'Example') {
                classfiles {
                    fileset(dir: "build/classes/")
                }
                sourcefiles {
                    fileset(dir: 'src/main/java')
                }
            }
            html(destdir: buildDir.path + '/reports/jacoco')
        }
    }
}
```

Output I think is causing the issue

```
[ant:report] Classes in bundle 'Example' do no match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
[ant:report] Execution data for class App does not match.
[ant:report] Execution data for class AppTest does not match.
```